# Connecting to DynamoDB from PHP running locally

Tags: php, database, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to connect to an AWS DynamoDB database that I've just set up. The connection should be created in a PHP page using the AWS\DynamoDb SDK. I have created a key and secret on AWS and I am successfully able to connect to the DB and retrieve an item from a table if I publish my code to my EC2 instance. However, I'd like to be able to test this out locally while running PHP on my localhost, but I'm getting the following error:

> Error executing "GetItem" on "https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

The code that I am using is the following:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
    use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;

    $sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
        'region'   => 'eu-central-1',
        'version'  => 'latest',
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => 'MY_KEY',
            'secret' => 'MY_SECRET'
        )
    ]);

    $dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();

    echo "Getting item...";

    try {
        $response = $dynamodb->getItem([
            'TableName' => 'MY_TABLE',
            'ConsistentRead' => true,
            'Key' => ['id' => ['N' => "1"], 'timestamp' => ['N' => "1000000000"]],
            'AttributesToGet' => ['name']
        ]);
        echo "getItem request was successful, result: ".$response;
    } catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        exit ("Unable to get data!");
    }
?>
```

How can I make this run on my localhost?

Comment: Either your OS's CA certificates are _wildly_ out of date, or what Leeroy has answered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to connect using something akin to a corporate proxy in which you must also configure the CA certificate:

> ###### AWS_CA_BUNDLE
>
> Specifies the path to a certificate bundle to use for HTTPS certificate validation.
> If defined, this environment variable overrides the value for the profile setting ca_bundle. You can override this environment variable by using the --ca-bundle command line parameter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-list